# Pasting multiple items into selectizeInput [shiny]

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building an application which uses selectize inputs with multiple = TRUE. I was looking for a way to allow users to paste in a comma separated list of items instead of having to enter each one in individually. It looks like selectize.js supports this as of version 0.12.0.

Is there a way to do this in Shiny?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R shiny: Copying Cells from Excel into SelectizeInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773066/r-shiny-copying-cells-from-excel-into-selectizeinput)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `strsplit`

```
choices <- "choice 1, some other choice, and another one"

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(selectInput("id", "select", strsplit(choices, ", ")[[1]])),
  function(...){}
)
```