# Copying cells from Excel and pasting them in a R Shiny application using text Area Input not functioning properly

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app which lets the user copy cells from Excel and paste in a textAreaInput in order to create a datatable out of the pasted cells. So far my code has worked with reference to this question - [R Shiny: Copying cells from excel and pasting them into Shiny app and then creating a Datatable with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742569/r-shiny-copying-cells-from-excel-and-pasting-them-into-shiny-app-and-then-creat)

```
ui <-fluidPage(
 textAreaInput("pasted", "paste text here"), 
 dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df_table <- reactive({ 
      if (input$pasted != '') {
        df_table <- fread(paste(input$pasted, collapse = "\n"))
        df_table <-as.data.frame(df_table)
        colnames(df_table) <- c("Method")
        df_table
        
      }
      
    })
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      df_table()
    }, filter="top", class = 'hover cell-border stripe', editable= TRUE,extensions= 'Buttons',
    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',pageLength =10,
                   buttons = c('copy','csv','excel','pdf','print'), scrollX=TRUE),server=FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works alright when I am pasting certain text and numbers into the textAreaInput. For example when I paste

[image]

I get the desired result-
[image]

1. But when I am pasting certain text into the textAreaInput it is not working properly. For example when I paste

[image]

I get a wrong result as "a" is missing -

[image]

2. Also, when I paste the following -

[image]

I get a wrong result -

[image]
with a warning in R saying -

[image]

I think this problem is because of the dashes (-) which is a special character in this case.

As a bigger picture, I think all these problems have something to do with the **collapse ="\n"** in paste within fread. Can someone please help me solve these problems?

**EDIT**
Funnily, I am not facing this issue no 2. when I am pasting two columns at the same time -
[image]

Comment: Try with adding `header = FALSE` to `fread`. By default it's set to "auto" and will treat the first row as column names if these are characters. That's why all data shows up if you paste only numerics.

Comment: Thank you for solving the first issue. It helped a lot. Can you please help me solve the second issue?

Comment: ... the second issue has to do with the seperators. `fread` treats the space as separator. Hence you end up with 9 column names in the first row but only three columns of data in the second. But not sure how to tackle this issue. Maybe you have to add an option to choose the separator. Or inform the user which character will be used as separator

Comment: Yes, I got that. Funnily it is working when I am pasting two columns together. I have updated the original post to show this under the Edit section.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just as alternate way of making a table, I like using rhandsontable to copy and paste from excel tables.

Comment: Can you give an example in this context? I can try implementing that instead if that deals with the separator issue.